# Get date creation or date modified of a file?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, system.io.directory

I want to get creation date, last modify date other details relating to  files, and adding them to a datagridview. Currently I am getting the file information by using `directory.getfiles`.
Here's what i got so far:

```
Dim paths() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("mypath")

For Each sFile As String In paths
    Dim fileNameOnly As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sFile)
    gridview.Rows.Add(fileNameOnly)
Next
```

Comment: what details are you wanting: create date. length, last accessed? _https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime(v=vs.110).aspx | https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.getfileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would grab both the created date, and the last write time.

```
For each sfile as datetime.tostring in paths
     Dim fileCreatedDate As DateTime = File.GetCreationTime(paths)
     Dim fileLastWrite as DateTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(path)
Next
```

To get files inbetween a date, try this..

```
Dim [date] As DateTime = firstdatevariable
While [date] <= seconddatevariable
     'add dates that are inbetween them
End While
```

Comment: how can i get only files in between a certain date to be added to my grid?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `DirectoryInfo` object to get your list of files you'll have access to more data:

```
Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("mypath")
```

Then your loop would look more like:

```
For Each fi In di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Dim fileNameOnly As String = fi.Name
    Dim createDate as Date = fi.CreationTime
    <etc...>
Next
```

See this for a full description of `FileInfo`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

*my vb may be rusty

Comment: this one works too but i just need something simple, thanks.

Comment: how can i get only files in between a certain date to be added to my grid?

Comment: Inside the For Each you can just wrap all your logic in an if statement comparing to the FileInfo properties. You could also use linq to limit your selection of returned filed from the GetFiles function on the DirectoryInfo but I'd only recommend that if you're familiar with linq (but it would be more efficient).

Answer (score 0):

I'm borrowing [this function](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?768447-Display-file-list-in-Datagridview).  It makes it really simple by filling a datatable, with that info, that you can further manipulate if needed.

```
gridview.DataSource = Fileinfo_To_DataTable("mypath")

 Private Function Fileinfo_To_DataTable(ByVal directory As String) As DataTable
        Try
            'Create a new data table
            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
            'Add the following columns: Name. Length Last Write Time, Creation Time
            dt.Columns.Addrange({New DataColumn("Name"), New DataColumn("Length", GetType(Long)), New DataColumn("Last Write Time", GetType(Date)), New DataColumn("Creation Time", GetType(Date))})
            'Loop through each file in the directory
            For Each file As IO.FileInfo In New IO.DirectoryInfo(directory).GetFiles
                'Create a new row
                Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                'Set the data
                dr(0) = file.Name
                dr(1) = file.Length
                dr(2) = file.LastWriteTime
                dr(3) = file.CreationTime

                'Add the row to the data table
                dt.Rows.Add(dr)
            Next

            'Return the data table
            Return dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)

           'Return nothing if something fails
            Return Nothing
        End Try
  End Function
```

Comment: this one works too but i just need something simple.

Comment: Maybe I misread the question, there's more code involved to manually add rows to the grid, afterwards, and my answer I felt satisfied the requirements in their entirety.

Comment: how can i get only files in between a certain date to be added to my grid?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest in my view would be something like this example.
I here look for a file called Symbols.csv in My Documents

```
Friend ReadOnly MyDocsFolder As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
Dim SymbolsFile As String = Path.Combine(MyDocsFolder, "Symbols.csv")
Dim dt As Date = File.GetLastWriteTime(SymbolsFile)
Text = "Data last saved at:  " & dt.ToShortDateString
```